# Config Serrices on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, web-server, windows-server-2003

Can someone please explain how to install/configure the following on a Windows 2003 Server?

DNS
Security Enhancements (very important)
Apache + PHP + Mysql
IIS

Thank you. This will be used as a dedicated server for a side project.

Comment: You're planning to run both Apache *and* IIS? Which one will have port 80?

Comment: Nothing wrong with running both - you can have Apache on port 80 doing reverse-proxy to IIS on port 8080 (or anything else.) And of course you only make 80 open to the world, and 8080 can only be contacted by localhost.

Comment: Don't believe I indicated there was anything wrong with it. But it would sure help to know what is planned before offering a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guide for installing [WAMP](http://www.eacomm.com/support/manuals/wamp_install/index.html).
Technet article on enabling DNSSEC on Server 2003 [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784518(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP / MySQL bits check out Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). The installer also handles most of the popular PHP apps as well.